# how to stop the logger output the logs on the console

Tags: python, logging

I just want to have `file_logger` to log all message to the dedicated file

But when I ran the script, it gave me all the logs both on the screen and file.

How could I get it.

```
def setup_logging(logging_file_path="logs/stdout.log"):
    global file_logger
    from os.path import dirname, realpath, isdir
    log_dir = dirname(realpath(logging_file_path))
    if not isdir(log_dir):
        os.makedirs(log_dir)  # it can built folder tree in one call
    file_logger = logging.getLogger()
    file_logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler("{0}".format(logging_file_path)))
    file_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_logger.propagate = False
    # file_logger.disabled = True # disable to log on the stdout

    return file_logger
```

Comment: You probably set another logger handle, by that you have 2 handlers for the same logger one for file and one for stdout.

Comment: Totally agreed with Kobi K. Anyways, you can try to `removeHandler(logging.StreamHandler)`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way the code you've shown would log to the console (as long as only `file_logger` is used for logging). To get console output, one would have had to have called `basicConfig()`, or called a function `logging.debug()` (i.e. not a logger method, but a convenience function in the `logging` module - which calls `basicConfig()` behind the scenes), or else explicitly added a `StreamHandler` (in code you haven't shown).